# Setting a cookie in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

I am loading a website using a WebBrowser's Navigate function, and I want the browser to load the page with a cookie I've given it.

The following code doesn't work:

```
wb.Navigate(url, null, null, "Cookie: " + cookie + "\n");
```

What am I doing wrong?  Will I have to use [InternetSetCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385108%28VS.85%29.aspx)?  This doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: Did You find an answer to this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like there is a better way:

Import the `InternetSetCookie` function:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
```

Create the `Cookie` object:

```
Cookie temp1 = new Cookie("KEY1", "VALUE1", "/Path/To/My/App", "/");
```

Call `InternetSetCookie` function to set the cookie for that URL

```
InternetSetCookie("https://my.url.com/Path/To/My/App", null, temp1.ToString() + "; expires = Sun, 01-Jan-2013 00:00:00 GMT");
```

`Navigate` the `WebBrowser` to the URL you would like to go to.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://my.url.com/Path/To/My/App");
```

Think this is the best solution for the issue :).

Comment: For anyone trying to get the 'expires =' part from a DateTime object, here's how to do it: <code> myDateTimeObj.ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " GMT" </code>

Comment: If you need to set a cookie in memory for the session only, you can call directly:
InternetSetCookieEx("https://my.url.com/Path/To/My/App", "KEY1", "VALUE1", NULL, NULL).

Note: there's a difference between calling InternetSetCookie and InternetSetCookieEx (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx). In practice, I've observed that any subsequent requests made by the page contain the cookie only if you use the "Ex" method.

Comment: I tried your code and could not get the cookies to show on my test website, [request.urih.com](http://request.urih.com/). I posted my solution using InternetSetCookieEx.

Answer (score 3):

[The proper way is using InternetSetCookieEx.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/internet-explorer-cookie-internals-faq)

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
static extern InternetCookieState InternetSetCookieEx(
    string lpszURL,
    string lpszCookieName,
    string lpszCookieData,
    int dwFlags,
    int dwReserved);

enum InternetCookieState : int
{
    COOKIE_STATE_UNKNOWN = 0x0,
    COOKIE_STATE_ACCEPT = 0x1,
    COOKIE_STATE_PROMPT = 0x2,
    COOKIE_STATE_LEASH = 0x3,
    COOKIE_STATE_DOWNGRADE = 0x4,
    COOKIE_STATE_REJECT = 0x5,
    COOKIE_STATE_MAX = COOKIE_STATE_REJECT
}
```

Here's some code to test it at a [website that shows your HTTP headers](http://request.urih.com/).

```
InternetSetCookieEx("http://request.urih.com/", null, "TestData=Test;", 0, 0);
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://request.urih.com/");
```

Comment: I am getting duplicate cookies when I do this. Have tried the cookie domain with and without ending slash. have tried the value with and without the semi-colon. Have tried not trimming the name/value pair and trimming. 

I am just wondering if in production you found a problem, fixed the setting of cookies and perhaps did not update your answer.

Comment: To clarify, when I set cookies I have saved in a database and then the 3rd party website sets them, they end up duplicating.

Comment: @Valamas yes, calling InternetSetCookie multiple times with same value will ends with duplicated cookies, you need to check and prevent this with InternetGetCookie, or save the cookies collection somewhere for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with cookies in thin control. There is overload for navigate method with cookie:

`string  cookie = webBrowser1.Document.Cookie.ToString(); webBrowser1.Navigate(url,"",null, cookie);`

In my case problem was resolved by redirecting to the page twice (or three times repeated) so look like this control enables cookies automatically:

```
           `webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
            waitforwebsite(300, webBrowser1);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
            waitforwebsite(300, webBrowser1);
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);`
```