# Need to log in to a website from my C# application

Tags: c#, menu

I wrote a C# application that has a log in menu and when the user types his information the program needs to send and log in with that info.After that show the logged in page with the WebBrowser class.For some reason it doesn't want to log in ,it directs to the website log in menu.I want the user to be able to log in from my c# application menu and don't have to see the Website Log in menu at all.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the above code:

- Formats the request with the user credentials
- Gets the response
- Attempts to put the returned cookie into a string

Nowhere do I see that same cookie being returned to the browser on subequent requests made by the webBrowser1:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("the website + the current session (cookieURL));
```

doesn't compile.

It appears [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830586/setting-a-cookie-in-a-webbrowser-control) may lead you to the correct solution.

Comment: Don't know how to add this "[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);".Missing assebly reference but i can't find this reference to add it.