# Setting cookie to webbrowser control, wb.document.cookie = "string";

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

I have a cookie stored in a string (acquired from cookiecontaier).
I am trying to set it to a webbrowser control like this:

```
wb.document.cookie = cookieString;
```

However i get a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I can see from the debugger that the cookieString is indeed populated and not null.

Do i need to specify the URL of which the cookie associated with?
Any Ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Tried this

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);


InternetSetCookie("http://myurl.com", null, cookieString + " expires = Sun, 01-Jan-2014 00:00:00 GMT");
```

Tried to use wireshark to see if the cookie got set, didnt seem like it :/.

Comment: What is null? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830586/setting-a-cookie-in-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: Thanks, 
Think i got stuck on this: 
Cookie temp1 = new Cookie("KEY1", "VALUE1", "/Path/To/My/App", "/");
As i allready have the cookie as a string i just did this:
InternetSetCookie("http://myurl.com", null, cookieString + " expires = Sun, 01-Jan-2014 00:00:00 GMT");

Still not working though, any ideas? any way to see if it has been set?