# How to pass HTTP headers field with Navigate method of WebBrowser control of C#

Tags: c#, cookies, webbrowser-control

I am trying to pass additional header field with Navigate method of WebBrowser control of C# but I am not able to achieve result. I need to set `UName=<actual username>` in Cookie field of HTTP header. My requirement is to hit one request url of type GET which will return JSP page so I used WebBrowser control of C#. I have done following:

```
string additionalHeader = "Cookie: UName=ppanchal;";
```

After above I called `webBrowser.Navigate(url,"",null,additionalHeader);` but I am getting `authorization failure error` because value of cookie UName has not been sent successfully. If I check in fiddler then I am not able to see my additional cookie UName in request header.

Let me know how to solve my problem. Note that I cannot use webrequest method as suggested in other posts. If I use that way and pass response of request to DocumentStream of webBrowser to have JSP/HTML page then it is giving me scripting error so I prefer to stay with above mentioned approach.

In iOS, UIWebView component provides method to load WebRequest object but similar kind of method is not there in WebBrowser control of C#.

Let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: The answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830586/setting-a-cookie-in-a-webbrowser-control.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks. Above link has solution for my problem.