# How to stay logged in a url if already logged in from an C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, url

We login to a website through a C# windows form application and now when we click on home page of that url we want to pass the session id / login info so that the browser opens up that url with user already logged in.

We use a webclient and get the user validated with a REST API passing user name and password. In response, we get a session id and user name back. We save this session id for further use and show a menu which can take you to a home page.

Now when we click on this home page button, we use following code to launch the url in the external browser,

```
  string url = "Test.com"
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

But when this url opens up, user is not logged in since I am not sure how can I use the returned session id here so that its the same session.

Can someone please help?

Comment: You'll have to add the necessary info to the URL. Test.com\sessionId=45

Comment: The web application can either allow the session id to be specified by cookie, query string, or either one. You need to make sure query string is not disallowed. You then will append the session id to the query string but you need to know the chosen query string request variable name. You will end up with something similar to `http://test.com/?sessionId=123456` where 123456 is the id of the session for the user.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that doing that would weaken security greatly.  Anyone can access the site using someone elses session.

Comment: Can I use any browser control where I can set the cookie and open the url in external browser..

Comment: [Setting a Cookie in WebBrowser Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830586/setting-a-cookie-in-a-webbrowser-control).