# Make WebBrowser control to delete its cache

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

so i am making a test application which login to a website and if given credentials are valid then separates them. when my webbrowser get successful login and program starts to repeat to process in order to check remaining credentials the logged in account gets cached. i tried

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely)
```

and couple of other methods like nevigating to about:blank but no success even when i restart the program webbrowser1 opens to cached logged in account. i want to make web browser at rully reset(startup) state after getting good login.

Comment: The login information isn't cached, it's stored in a cookie. Cache ≠ Cookies. Caching is when the browser stores a local copy of certain **resources** (CSS/JS-files, images, etc.), whereas it is the cookies that store **information**. You've got to clear all Internet Explorer's cookies if you want to remove the login information (or at least remove that specific cookie, if you know its name).

Comment: how to find that specific cookie and remove it

Comment: Google Chrome has the ability to view a site's cookies, see: [https://superuser.com/a/874934](https://superuser.com/a/874934). Then you've either got to edit the cookie's expire date by P/Invoking `InternetSetCookie()` (see: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031887](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031887)) or remove all cookies from the current document by setting [**`WebBrowser.Document.Cookie`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.cookie(v=vs.110).aspx) to an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable cache (including cookies) before navigating to the site.

To do so, you can use [`InternetSetOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetoptiona) API function and set the value of `INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR(81)` option to `INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST(3)` value.

**Example**

I tried the following example, which disables cache and while I've logged in `outlook.com`, but it works like starting a new session:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
    Public Shared Function InternetSetOption(hInternet As IntPtr, dwOption As Integer, _
        lpBuffer As IntPtr, dwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
        Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 3)
        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 81, ptr, 4)
        Marshal.Release(ptr)
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://outlook.com")
    End Sub
End Class
```

To find more information about these flags, take a look at [Windows Internet Option Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinInet/option-flags).

Note: You can find a C# version of this answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133282/3110834) in my other post.