# Clear web browser cookies winforms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How I can clear cookies for web browser control winforms C# , is there any way to clear cookies problematically in winforms web browser control

Answer (score 2):

You can disable cache (including cookies) before navigating to the site. To do so, you can use [`InternetSetOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetoptiona) API function and set the value of `INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR(81)` option to `INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST(3)` value.

**Example**

The following example, works like starting a new session. While I've logged in to the `outlook.com` on my machine, but when I open this application and browse `outlook.com` after disabling cookies and cache, it works like starting a new session and I need to login to outlook.com:

```
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption,
    IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
    Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 3);
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 81, ptr, 4);
    Marshal.Release(ptr);
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://outlook.com");
}
```

To find more information about these flags, take a look at [Windows Internet Option Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinInet/option-flags).

Note: You can find a VB.NET version of this answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51117361/3110834) in my other post.