# How to fix Windows internet explorer and webbrowser form control session problem?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, registry, webbrowser-control

I created something in C# that just uses the C# default WEBBROWSER CONTROL on a FORM CONTROL. My application logs in on the website using the WEBBROWSER CONTROL located on NEW Form2() then close(). Afterward it will browse the website using another WEBBROWSER CONTROL on NEW Form3(). This applications works on some windows and some not.

The problem is when I open Form3() , it forces me back to login page which means the session or cookie is not shared or saved. I need it to use old session and cookies after I logged in using another WEBBROWSER CONTROL on a past Form()

I have solved this before by following a page I read online but I no longer has access to it and didn't remember it by heart, big regret.

However the trick was related to something on the Server Manager > Internet Explorer or Registry I don't quite remember since I only did it once and it works.

Anyone knows how to solve this please help, much appreciation on any information.

Comment: It should share the cookie by default. But if for any reason it's not sharing the cookie, try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133282/3110834) by a small change, use `Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 1);`. For more information take a look at the links which are shared in the post.

Comment: @RezaAghaei It worked magically. Very different from my last trick manually changing the IE option settings. Thank you once again!