# How to clear IE WebBrowser Control cookies

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have tried INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION ,however this does not delete cookies
Only way I have found is to remove IE browser cookies itself using  RunDll32.exe InetCpl. cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2. This works perfectly fine however this brings up IE clearing history dialog
Is there any other way of removing clearing WebBrowser Control cookies

Comment: [Clear web browser cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133282/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your reply,I need persistent cookies for other reason and want to clear cookies only on certain action

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: From [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/450014/clearmytracksbyprocess-all-options/1006718#1006718), there's an option `256` means `Do not Show GUI when running the cache clear`. You could try to combine these values together to see if it can hide the dialog window. According to the answer, by adding values together we can get aggregate functionality. So you could try `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 258`.

Comment: @YuZhou I tried this,still I am IE clearing cookies dialog

Comment: @Yu Zhou I am still seeing IE clearing cookies dialog

Comment: It seems that this solution doesn't work any more in win10. I test in win7 and it still can work. In win10, I try to combine the two commands line by line and the dialog won't show: `RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 256 ^ RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2`

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks for your help,I will confirm if its clearing cookies

Comment: @YuZhou I tried this,it is not showing UI RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 256 ^ RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1,however it is not deleting history

Comment: @Yu Zhou I tried this,it is not showing UI RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 256 ^ RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1,however it is not deleting history

Comment: @YuZhou Do you have other suggestion

Comment: Maybe due to some security concers, we can't use the way above to delete cookies silently any more. I'll try to research if there're other ways to achieve this and inform you if I find something.

Comment: After researching, I think we can't do it silently. You could refer to the accepted answer in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ce81943b-32b8-437b-b620-171c3d5893e7/inetcplcpl-with-clearmytracksbyprocess?forum=ieextensiondevelopment). As it says, there's no document about the command and it looks like the behavior of the command has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not go into such complicated stuff . Just download ccleaner or open it if you laready have and then go to custom clean -> applications and tick the checkbox under the heading internet explorer -> "Cookies and other site data"

If you want to delete or disable IE go to settings-> or control panel if you do not have windows 10 OS and then go to Programs and features -> uninstall a program -> isable some windows features -> untick checkbox "Internet Explorer 9 or 11(whichever version you have)"
Hope you like the answer and works for you

Comment: I have to clear IE cookies from my application ,not from third party application.Sorry this was not what I was looking for

Comment: Okay refer this site then - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17442/windows-internet-explorer-delete-manage-cookies

Comment: I am looking for clearing cookies through command line

Answer (score 0):

This link can be refered to clear IE cookies silently
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15319/A-Cleanup-API-for-Windows

```
__declspec( dllexport ) BOOL Delete_IECookies(BOOL bDeleteCookies, 
                                                       BOOL bDeleteCookiesIndex)
{
    TCHAR szUserProfile[200]; 
    TCHAR szFilePath[200];
    HANDLE hCacheEnumHandle  = NULL;
    LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO lpCacheEntry = NULL;
    DWORD  dwSize = 4096; // initial buffer size

    // Delete index.dat if requested. Be sure that index.dat is not locked.
    if(bDeleteCookiesIndex)
    {
        // Retrieve from environment user profile path.
        ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%", szUserProfile, 
                                                         sizeof(szUserProfile)); 
        wsprintf(szFilePath, "%s%s", szUserProfile, "\\Cookies\\index.dat");

        DeleteFile(szFilePath);

        if(!bDeleteCookies) return TRUE;
    }
    
    // Enable initial buffer size for cache entry structure.
    lpCacheEntry = (LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO) new char[dwSize];
    lpCacheEntry->dwStructSize = dwSize;
    
    // URL search pattern (1st parameter) options are:  "cookie:", "visited:", 
    // or NULL ("*.*").
    hCacheEnumHandle = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(_T("cookie:") /* in */, 
                                 lpCacheEntry /* out */, &dwSize /* in, out */);
    
    // First, obtain handle to internet cache with FindFirstUrlCacheEntry
    // for late use with FindNextUrlCacheEntry.
    
    if(hCacheEnumHandle != NULL) 
    {
         DeleteUrlCacheEntry(lpCacheEntry->lpszSourceUrlName);
    }
    else
    {
        switch(GetLastError())
        {
            case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                lpCacheEntry = (LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO) new char[dwSize];
                lpCacheEntry->dwStructSize = dwSize;

                // Repeat first step search with adjusted buffer, exit if not
                // found again (in practice one buffer's size adustment is  
                // always OK).
                hCacheEnumHandle = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry(NULL, lpCacheEntry, 
                                                                       &dwSize);
                if(hCacheEnumHandle != NULL) 
                {
                    DeleteUrlCacheEntry(lpCacheEntry->lpszSourceUrlName);
                    break;        
                }
                else
                {
                    // FindFirstUrlCacheEntry fails again, return.
                    return FALSE; 
                }
            default:
                FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheEnumHandle);
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    
    // Next, use hCacheEnumHandle obtained from the previous step to delete 
    // subsequent items of cache.

    do 
    {
         // Notice that return values of FindNextUrlCacheEntry (BOOL) and 
         // FindFirstUrlCacheEntry (HANDLE) are different.

         if(FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheEnumHandle, lpCacheEntry, &dwSize))
         {
            DeleteUrlCacheEntry(lpCacheEntry->lpszSourceUrlName);
         }
         else
         {
             switch(GetLastError())
             {
                 case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                    lpCacheEntry = (LPINTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO) 
                                                               new char[dwSize];
                    lpCacheEntry->dwStructSize = dwSize;

                    // Repeat next step search with adjusted buffer, exit if 
                    // error comes up again ((in practice one buffer's size 
                    // adustment is always OK).

                    if(FindNextUrlCacheEntry(hCacheEnumHandle, lpCacheEntry, 
                                                                       &dwSize)) 
                    {
                        DeleteUrlCacheEntry(lpCacheEntry->lpszSourceUrlName);
                        break;          
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // FindFirstUrlCacheEntry fails again, return.
                        FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheEnumHandle);
                        return FALSE; 
                    }
                    break;
                 case ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS:
                     FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheEnumHandle);
                     return TRUE; 
                 default:
                     FindCloseUrlCache(hCacheEnumHandle);
                     return FALSE;
             }
         } 
    } while (TRUE);

    return FALSE; // never here
}
```